# Probloem Save to Excel using PHPExcel PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a confused with my PHPExcel when save file. 
This is my code

```
$filename = 'test';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');

$template = 'C:/xampp5.9/htdocs/MTD/assets/media/template/test.xls'; 

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($template);

$objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->mergeCells('A9:B9')->setCellValue('A9', 'Test');
$rows = 15;
$col = 0;

$dt_download = ['rizky', 'Arie', 'Ester'];

for ($i=0; $i < COUNT($dt_download); $i++) {
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col+$i, $rows+$i, $dt_download[$i]);
}

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit();
```

I Just have a result in my console like this :
[image]

And nothing file come as a downloaded file. Please tell me how to fix it, cause I have nothing error in my code in console.

I'm using post method for this

Comment: What version of PHP is installed in your system?

Comment: my php version is `PHP Version 5.6.19`

Comment: Any warnings in your php error log?

Comment: I Just Found this error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'header'`

Comment: If you're getting `unexpected 'header'` in the error log, then it likely means that you have a missing semi-colon at the end of the previous line

Comment: I have fix that, still not working for downloading file, any suggestion ?

Comment: Something is confusing the headings, and telling the browser to open the file in the browser itself, rather than open the save file dialogue.... are tyou running this from any kind of framework that might be sending its own headers that conflict with the headers in your code here?

Comment: Use your browser developer tools t look at the headers being returned from this request, see if they actually match up with the headers that you are sending

Comment: Hi @MarkBaker , sorry just reply, I will try that, I'm using codeigniter framework

Comment: @MarkBaker I have trying using network in developer tools, and the header is match with my request in phpexcel download and status is ok, and no downloaded file appears here

Comment: Well something is telling the browser to display the file rather than to open the save dialogue.... that's likely to be either the headers, or something being injected at the beginning of the file like spaces.... or are you usig an Ajax call to request the file rather than a html link?

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->mergeCells('A9:B9')->setCellValue('A9', Test);
```

Where have you defined Test. Is it a constant, string or what kind of variable?

because of that it will generate an error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
```

and your code will not work.

if Test is just a string then you have to put it inside quotations like this

```
 $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->mergeCells('A9:B9')->setCellValue('A9', 'Test');
```